# How to view list of fellow classmates in GridView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, gridview

I am working on a social networking assignment.  I have already got the database working and I have to provide a page to allow user to view the list of student names from his/her class.

This is how my database roughly looks like:

Name of Table: **studentTable**

```
name  |  class
------+---------
John  |  classA
Tim   |  classB
Kate  |  classA
Max   |  classA
```

For example, if John logs into the website, he will be able to view Kate and Max as his classmate and not Tim in a GridView.

This is my SqlDataSource code:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:StudentCS %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT [name], [class] FROM [studentTable] WHERE ([class] = @class)">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="class" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

May I know how this can be accomplished with GridView or any other ways?

Answer (score 1):

Have you included your `GridView` to your .aspx page as yet? if not,

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1"  DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"  
AutoGenerateColumns="true" runat="server">
</asp:GridView>
```

note: You will need some kind of login mechanism so that you can identify which user logs in so that you can query the database to get his/her class to pass as your parameter.

Comment: OP can use `User.Identity.Name` to get loggedin user name.

Answer (score -1):

Try the following this may help you solve it. You will have to save the logged in student name in the session i-e) Session["StudentName"]

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:StudentCS %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT [name], [class] FROM [studentTable] AS A , [studentTable] AS B WHERE A.Class = B.Class AND A.name = @StudentName ">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:SessionParameter SessionField="StudentName" Name="StudentName" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```